# Split string at specific character with optional comma

Tags: javascript

I need to split a string for each `d` chracter, which has an optional comma in front.

```
d(ii)d(ii)
d(ii),d(ii)
dd
d,d
```

should result in two element arrays:

```
d(ii) | d(ii)
d(ii) | d(ii)
d | d
d | d
```

Also a single `d` string should result in an array with this single element.

I've started with `string.split(',')` but obviously it doesn't take care about the comma

Comment: Could you just remove all the commas before you begin splitting?

Comment: @chrisz Oh... yes... this could be an option..

Comment: @user3142695, so your input is an array of strings or a single multiline string?

Comment: and how should this string `a(d,bb),d(1),d(d,2)` be treated ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function splitD(str){
  var result =  str.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/d/g, " d").trim().split(" ");
  console.log(result);
  return result;

}

splitD("d(ii)d(ii)");
splitD("d(ii),d(ii)");
splitD("dd");
splitD("d,d");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split with a positive lookahead of `d` and an optional comma in front of.

```js
console.log(['d(ii)d(ii)', 'd(ii),d(ii)', 'dd', 'd,d'].map(s => s.split(/,?(?=d)/)));
```